# How to debug "Inconsistent local/global assignment" in l3seq (expl3)?

Tags: expl3, latex3, debugging

I'm trying to debug an `expl3` code that uses`l3seq` and `seq_gput_right`. By adding the `enable-debug` and reviewing the code I get the error:

```
! LaTeX3 Error: Inconsistent local / global assignment
```

That was previously hidden (but worked fine). The error comes from the line `\seq_gput_right:cn`, but if I change it to `\seq_put_right:cn` the error disappears but the code does not work as it should.

The example file is the following, I have occupied it a lot of times and I had not noticed the error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[enable-debug]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\debug_on:n{check-declarations,deprecation,check-expressions}
% internal
\NewDocumentCommand{\_appendcontents}{ m +m }
 {
  \mymodule_append_contents:nn { #1 } {{ #2 }}
 }
% external
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usecontents}{O{1}m}
 {
  \mymodule_use_contents:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \mymodule_append_contents:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_if_exist:cF { l_mymodule_contents_#1_seq }
   { \seq_new:c { l_mymodule_contents_#1_seq } }
  \__mymodule_append_contents:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mymodule_append_contents:nn #1 #2
 {
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    %\seq_put_right:cn { l_mymodule_contents_#1_seq } { ##1 }
    \seq_gput_right:cn { l_mymodule_contents_#1_seq } { ##1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \mymodule_use_contents:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_item:cn { l_mymodule_contents_#2_seq } { #1 }
 }

% [key=val]
\keys_define:nn { mymodule }
  {
    save-cmd  .tl_set:N         = \l_mymodule_cmd_save_tl,
    save-cmd  .initial:n        = contents,
    show-cmd  .bool_set:N       = \l_mymodule_cmd_show_tl,
    show-cmd  .initial:n        = false,    
  }

% \Scontents[...]{...} 
\NewDocumentCommand{\Scontents}{ o +m }
  {
   \group_begin:
   \IfNoValueF { #1 } { \keys_set:nn { mymodule } { #1 } }
   \_appendcontents{\l_mymodule_cmd_save_tl}{ #2 } % add to list
   \IfBooleanT { \l_mymodule_cmd_show_tl } { \usecontents[-1]{ \l_mymodule_cmd_save_tl} }
   \group_end:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\section{Default list}
Use command \par
\Scontents{saved in list \{contents\} index 1}\par
\Scontents{saved in list \{contents\} index 2}
Show saved\par
\usecontents[2]{contents}\par
\usecontents[1]{contents}

\section{Custom list}
Use command \par
\Scontents[save-cmd=test-cmd]{saved in list \{test-cmd\} index 1}
\Scontents[save-cmd=test-cmd]{saved in list \{test-cmd\} index 2}
\Scontents[save-cmd=test-cmd]{saved in list \{test-cmd\} index 3}
Show saved in list \{test-cmd\}\par
\usecontents[3]{test-cmd}\par
\usecontents[1]{test-cmd}\par
\usecontents[2]{test-cmd}\par
Add one more to list \{contents\}\par
\Scontents{saved in list \{contents\} index 3}
Show saved in list \{contents\}\par
\usecontents[3]{contents}\par
\usecontents[2]{contents}\par
\usecontents[1]{contents}
\end{document}
```

How do I fix this?

Saludos

Comment: Don't use `\seq_gput_right:Nn` with a local variable (name beginning with `\l_`). Global assignments must be done on global variables (name beginning with `\g_`). By the way, it's quite strange to define a user command with `_` in its name (like `\_appendcontents`).

Comment: OK, I understand about the use of `\l_` and `\g_`, `\_appendcontents` is an internal command, the user command is `\Scontents` ( `\_appendcontents` need double `{{}}`). The issue of changing the locale variables by global to disappear already cracked lists, edit the sample file a bit.

Comment: If it is an internal command, it should have its regular prefix and be defined with `\cs_new_protected:Npn`

Comment: @egreg My attempts in that aspect have failed, I lose the lists already created, could you show me an example?

Comment: If I do `\Scontents{Hello world}`, the sequence will contain ten items `{H}{e}{l}{l}{o}{W}{o}{r}{l}{d}`. Is that what you really want?

Comment: @egreg No! ... in my mind (and according to what I think) it should contain
`Hello world` ...(only a one item)...Now I'm lost :(

Comment: You're doing `\tl_map_inline:nn`…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is doing a global assignment to a local variable.

Variables have names starting with `\l_` for *local* ones, `\g_` for *global* ones. You should use a global variable with `\seq_gput_right:Nn` (or variant thereof).

Boolean variables have names ending in `_bool`, not `_tl`.

Also, commands defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` should not have `_` in them.

Another problem: you're doing a pointless `\tl_map_inline:nn` loop.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[enable-debug]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\debug_on:n{check-declarations,deprecation,check-expressions}

% external
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usecontents}{O{1}m}
 {
  \mymodule_use_contents:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
% \Scontents[...]{...} 
\NewDocumentCommand{\Scontents}{ O{} +m }
  {
   \group_begin:
   \keys_set:nn { mymodule } { #1 }
   \mymodule_append_contents:nn { \l_mymodule_cmd_save_tl } { #2 } % add to list
   \bool_if:NT \l_mymodule_cmd_show_bool
    { \mymodule_use_contents:nn { -1 } { \l_mymodule_cmd_save_tl } }
   \group_end:
  }

% internal
\cs_new_protected:Npn \mymodule_append_contents:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_if_exist:cF { g_mymodule_contents_#1_seq }
   { \seq_new:c { g_mymodule_contents_#1_seq } }
  \seq_gput_right:cn { g_mymodule_contents_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \mymodule_use_contents:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_item:cn { g_mymodule_contents_#2_seq } { #1 }
 }

% [key=val]
\keys_define:nn { mymodule }
  {
    save-cmd  .tl_set:N         = \l_mymodule_cmd_save_tl,
    save-cmd  .initial:n        = contents,
    show-cmd  .bool_set:N       = \l_mymodule_cmd_show_bool,
    show-cmd  .default:n        = true,
    show-cmd  .initial:n        = false,
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Default list}

Use command \par

\Scontents{saved in list \{contents\} index 1}\par
\Scontents{saved in list \{contents\} index 2}

Show saved\par
\usecontents[2]{contents}\par
\usecontents[1]{contents}

\section{Custom list}

Use command \par

\Scontents[save-cmd=test-cmd]{saved in list \{test-cmd\} index 1}
\Scontents[save-cmd=test-cmd]{saved in list \{test-cmd\} index 2}
\Scontents[save-cmd=test-cmd]{saved in list \{test-cmd\} index 3}

Show saved in list \{test-cmd\}\par
\usecontents[3]{test-cmd}\par
\usecontents[1]{test-cmd}\par
\usecontents[2]{test-cmd}\par

Add one more to list \{contents\}\par

\Scontents{saved in list \{contents\} index 3}

Show saved in list \{contents\}\par
\usecontents[3]{contents}\par
\usecontents[2]{contents}\par
\usecontents[1]{contents}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll take note of all your comments, use `enable-debug` is the equivalent of using `use strict;` in `Perl` (it should be part of `xparse` options) ... You can add something to your answer ... Is there any difference between using `l3clist` and `l3seq` for this specific case? ...
PD: Reading the documentation of expl3 (`TeXLive2019`) I notice that within the current members of the `LaTeX3` project your name is not included ... you no longer participate in the project?

Thanks for all

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL I'd prefer sequences. The list is a bit outdated: https://www.latex-project.org/about/team/

Comment: The line `{ \mymodule_use_contents { -1 } { \l_mymodule_cmd_save_tl } }` does not work if this `show-cmd = true`. Change it to `{ \usecontents[-1] { \l_mymodule_cmd_save_tl } }` and it works.

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL Sorry, fixed typo

Comment: Thanks, I noticed the lack `:nn` after writing the comment, you can take a look at  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/488175/7832 (is part of the same idea , pass `contents` or `\macro` to a list). Saludos